# in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) Did you mean? catch. Ruby and CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

Trying to convert links into images with CSV. When running my code I get the error 
in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method`match' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  catch

Code --

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'tempfile'
require 'uri'
require 'csv'

DOWNLOAD_DIR = "#{Dir.pwd}/BD/"
CSV_FILE = "#{Dir.pwd}/konvertera.csv"

def downloadFile(id, url, format)
  begin
   open("#{DOWNLOAD_DIR}#{id}.#{format}", "wb+") do |file|
   file << open(url).read
   puts "Successfully downloaded #{url} to #{DOWNLOAD_DIR}#{id}.#{format}"
 end
rescue
  puts "404 not found #{url}"
 end
end


CSV.foreach(CSV_FILE, headers: true, col_sep: ";") do |row|
 id = row[0]
 format = row[1].match(/BD\.(.+)$/)&.captures.first
 url = row[1].gsub ".pdf", ""
 downloadFile(id, url, format)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CSV.foreach(CSV_FILE, headers: true, col_sep: ";") do |row|
  # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
  next unless row[0] && row[1]
  # ⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑
  id = row[0]
  format = row[1].match(/BD\.(.+)$/)&.captures.first
  url = row[1].gsub ".pdf", ""
  downloadFile(id, url, format)
end
```